# .usesLineFragmentOrigin drawing option is not working as it supposed according its description in docs

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring

Here I am trying to draw a NSAttributeString by calling it's draw(with rect:options:context:) function and setting options parameter to NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin. Actually, yes, NSAttributeString draws its string[image], but if change rect parameter in draw(with rect:options:context:) fucntion, to smaller frame MSAttributeString just cuts its portion and thats it.[image] But according to .usesLineFragmentOrigin description in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1524971-draw

> If usesLineFragmentOrigin is specified in options, it wraps the string
>   text as needed to make it fit. If the string is too big to fit
>   completely inside the rectangle, the method scales the font or adjusts
>   the letter spacing to make the string fit within the given bounds.
>   Here is my code:

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let anotheR: anotherView = anotherView(frame: view.bounds)
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    view.addSubview(anotheR)
    anotheR.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    anotheR.draw(CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 50, height: 10))

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

class anotherView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
    let suprect = rect
 var string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s." as NSString
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string as String)

    layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    layer.borderWidth = 2
 let context =   NSStringDrawingContext()
    context.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
    attributedString.draw(with: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 80, height: 300), options:    NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin , context: context)


}
}
```

But, no, does not seem to do it job. Maybe somewhere I am wrong? Maybe it supposed to work somehow else? Please if someone know, give me a clue. Thank you!

Comment: Am sorry for all of Apple as a company that this question was never answered-- by ANYONE.  Apple as a company has failed here.